# ADF CreateInsert Action adds two records in ADF Table

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I am currently working on a project where the users require data entry screens modeled after a spreadsheet.

Everything was working fine and data entry was working as designed. All of a sudden whenever the user clicks on the button bound to the **CreateInsert** event, it adds two rows in the ADF Table instead of one.

**Behavior screenshot:**
[image]

Moreover, when I attempt to rollback the ADF transaction, the number of records are multiplied. Meaning, I click **Rollback** bound button the records disappear. Then when I click **CreateInsert** again, I get **4** extra new records.

**Multiplied records screenshot:**
[image]

**JSF Page:**

```html
<af:commandButton actionListener="#{bindings.CreateInsert.execute}" text="#{label.strCreateNew}" styleClass="btnGeneral" disabled="#{!bindings.CreateInsert.enabled}" id="b1"/>
```

I have also attempted to override the **CreateInsert** event by writing my own code. It still exhibited the same behavior.

**Custom Code:**

```
 public void doAddNewRecord(ActionEvent actionEvent)
 {
    ApplicationModule am = null;
    try
    {
        am = ADFUtils.getApplicationModuleForDataControl("AppModuleDataControl");
        ViewObject vo = am.findViewObject("NssFiuMnyLndryTrrFinView1");

        Row row = vo.createRow();
        vo.insertRow(row);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        /*custom exception handling code*/
    }
 }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This means that you do not have a primary key in your View Object or the primary key has duplicate values

Comment: I have set the primary key in the View Object to be the RowId. I know its not the best practice, but the business are pretty vague about how the data should be controlled. Anyway, I will try to configure a primary key for the View Object and update this accordingly.

Comment: Try to include more columns in the primary key because the rowid can not be known until the record has been saved

Comment: I did what you've suggested, added two more columns to the primary key to both the entity and the view object. Same behavior.

Comment: Did you removed the RowId ?

Comment: Tried that, removed RowId created a new column with a sequence binding and set it on database, entity and view levels as primary key alone. Same behavior. I am starting to think that this might be a bug with Weblogic 12.2.1.0.0.

Comment: I remember that I changed the CreateInsert  with Create Operation. But It seems it is a bug as you said